# Estimate video size for different resolutions

Tags: video

I am developing a web application for a customer, basically I need to estimate the costs of storing photos/videos on AWS for our user database.

I'd like to know the average size (or size range) of 1 minute of video for different resolutions (240p, 360p, 480p, 720p, 1080p)

I understand that there are so many video format, that an uncompressed video at 360p could be as big asthe same video in 720p compressed, but I really need an average on what you are expected to find on the internet coming from regular users.

(We may enforce video format / size restrictions depending on that)

Can you help me estimate the size of 1min of video for those different resolution formats (240p -> 1080p) assuming reasonable web quality and "usual" compression formats ? Are there maybe statistics available on the internet that can estimate typical video size ?

Answer (score 2):

The video file size depends a little on the format (the container, like .avi or .mkv) but depends a lot on the codec used for the compression and they can be very different depending on the content - usually a video showing slow moving content like a screencast takes less space than one showing fast moving content like a gameplay.
In any case I thought that I would give this a try by running a little experiment: I took a 1080p video and resized it to the other resolutions so I will give you the figures in percentage to give you a better idea. Keep in mind that a one-minute 1080p video can be typically from 5MB to 15MB ...

```
1080p = 100.0%
 720p =  66.7%
 480p =  47.1%
 360p =  39.0%
 240p =  31.6%
```

Comment: Interesting approach. But I'd say that people also use different codecs depending on the resolution, therefore simply resizing probably doesn't reflect so well reality because you use the same codec that may be less adapted for low-res ?